# Auxiliary Angle Cambridge Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

**I came across the following question in the Year 12 Extension 1 Cambridge textbook:**

Let $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$ be the solutions of the equation $a\cos4\theta + b\sin4\theta=c$ such that $\tan\theta_1$, $\tan\theta_2$, $\tan\theta_3$ and $\tan\theta_4$ are distinct. Use the product of the roots of a quartic equation to prove that $\tan\theta_1\tan\theta_2\tan\theta_3\tan\theta_4=1$.

Honestly speaking, I have no idea how to even get started on this question here so any direction would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Use $x=\tan(2\theta)$ then you get a polynomial equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula)

Comment: ... and then one of Viète's formulas (the product of roots of $at^4+bt^3+ct^2+dt+e$ is equal to $e/a$)